# Как распараллелить запросы к базе данных

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня на сервис поступают запросы по сбору информации. По одному запросу от клиента в цикле делается 1000 обращаений к БД. Объединить все маленькие запросы в один большой нет возможности.

Все это происходит примерно так:

```
   rows = [] 
   for receiver in receivers:
        rows.append(db_connection.connection('mybd').select(query, [begin, end, receiver]))
```

Есть ли какой-нибудь простой способ сделать несколько подклчючений к БД и распараллелить запросы ?

Comment: Простой способ - стартануть несколько потоков, организовать очередь. В очередь пихать запросы, свободный поток забирает из очереди запрос, выполняет его. Обычный Producer-Consumer. Но это плохое, негодное решение - хорошим было бы написать некостыльный SQL.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону асинхронных запросов в БД: Например [asyncpg](https://github.com/MagicStack/asyncpg)

Comment: в такой подстановке любой подход, используемый для concurrent программирования подойдёт. Наилучшего результата дадут, конечно, методы, которые используют особенности ваших запросов к БД. Если не учитывать, то методы абсолютно такие же как например, для [создания множества http запросов](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27986480/4279) (thread/connection pool, async. IO).